# What is the meaning of this Eclipse icon?

Tags: icons, eclipse, ide

I've been coding with the Eclipse IDE for some time now, and I renamed a few of my files, and this icon has popped up. I did some research and didn't discover anything. What does it mean?

Check this image (I've circled the icons in red):

[image]

The icons look like little snowflakes/asterisks.
What are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The icons look like little snowflakes/asterisks. What are they?

> It means the file is staged for commit, see the section [Icon
> decorations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations)
> in the eclipse wiki
>
> > - staged - The resource has changes which have been added to the index. Note that adding changes to the index is currently possible
> >   only in the commit dialog via the context menu of a resource.
> > - partially-staged - The resource has changes which are added to the index and additional changes in the working tree that neither reached
> >   the index nor have been committed to the repository.
>
> that is, files which are already tracked by git and changes to them
> were staged with `git add (-p) <file>`

Source [Egit “*” symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3691706/3536342), answer by [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)